# Can some one explain this code for finding the greatest increase for a list. C#

Tags: c#

I found the following code in a book.  I honestly don't know how to explain and comment the stuff I found in the book.

```
private int GreatestIncrease(List<int> PopulationList)                              //Imports the population list to Greatest.

{
    int amountOfChange = 0;
    int changeInYears = 0;
    int i;
    int theChange = 0;
    int currentYear = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < PopulationList.Count(); i++)
    {
        theChange = PopulationList[i] - PopulationList[i - 1];
        currentYear = i;

        if (theChange > amountOfChange)
        {
            amountOfChange = theChange;
            changeInYears = i;
        }
    }

    return changeInYears;
}

private int LeastIncrease(List<int> PopulationList)                                 //Imports the population list to Least.
{
    int firstItem = PopulationList.First();
    int lastItem = PopulationList.Last();

    int amountOfChange = (lastItem - firstItem);
    int changeInYears = 0;
    int i;
    int theChange = 0;
    int CurrentYear = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < PopulationList.Count(); i++)
    {
        theChange = PopulationList[i] - PopulationList[i - 1];
        CurrentYear = i;

        if (theChange < amountOfChange)
        {
            amountOfChange = theChange;
            changeInYears = i;
        }
    }

    return changeInYears;
}
```

Comment: To whom will you be explaining this code that you don't understand?

Comment: my instructor likes us to explain everything in graphic detail. He said that we can use any resources as long as we understand it.

Comment: Starting at the second item in the list, you are looping through the list, comparing each element and the element before it by subtracting the values. If the difference is larger than the previously stored largest difference (you're storing it in a temporary variable `amountOfChange`, starts off with 0 value) then it stores the amount of change this time, and the current position in the list. At the end, it simply returns that position.

Comment: Thank you guys. that makes a lot more sense now. the book didn't even explain it at all.

Comment: Sorry I'm just a noob. I only started learning Visual Studio C# about 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I'm wondering which book you found this! There's absolutely no correlation between the function name and what it returns. The variable ~CurrentYear~ always holds the index value, and never an year! Are you really studying from this book?!

Comment: Yea, I lament the authors of this book for not using solid method names, etc... Unless this chapter is "How to interpret other writers terribly written code." =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? (Honestly your question is vague and open ended...)

The following code displays some information to the page when some button is clicked. It shows the average change in population, the year in which the population increased the most, and the least.

```
    private void btnFindPopulation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("USPopulation.txt");                     //Open the USPopulation.txt file.

        List<int> PopulationList = new List<int>();                                     //Creates a list and a new object of the list.

        int startingyear = 1950;                                                        //Creates the starting year for the index.

        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)                                                  //While not at the end of the list.
        {
            PopulationList.Add(int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine()));                        //Read the scores into the list.
        }


        inputFile.Close();                                                              //Close the file.

       int numberOfYears = PopulationList.Count();                                      //Counts the amount of items in the population and assigns it to number of years.

       int average = Average(PopulationList, numberOfYears);                            //Sends the population list and numberofyears into average.

       lblAnnualChange.Text = average.ToString();                                       //Assigns the new average into the lblAnnualChange.

       int biggest = startingyear + GreatestIncrease(PopulationList);                   //Adds the starting year with the index count of the biggest number.

       lblGreatestIncrease.Text = biggest.ToString();                                   //Assigns the biggest into the lblGreatestIncrease.

       int least = startingyear + LeastIncrease(PopulationList);                        //Sends the population list and number of years to least number.

       lblLeastIncrease.Text = least.ToString();                                        //Assigns the least into the lblLeastIncrease.
    }
```

Other methods are called to collate the data: Average is super strait forward. But GreatestIncrease and LeastIncrease are searching the list of data (which it assumes is already ordered from earliest to latest, a poor assumption, if you ask me...) to determine which year (or list index, actually) contains the largest change (or smallest change, in the case of LeastIncrease).

The Method name is poorly given, and doesn't do a good job of conveying what data it is returning. If I were reviewing this code, I would recommend that the method names be changed to "GetIndexOfGreatestIncrease" and "GetIndexOfLeastIncrease" respectively.

```
    private int GreatestIncrease(List<int> PopulationList)                              //Imports the population list to Greatest.

    {
        int amountOfChange = 0;
        int changeInYears = 0;
        int i;
        int theChange = 0;
        int currentYear = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < PopulationList.Count(); i++)
        {
            theChange = PopulationList[i] - PopulationList[i - 1];
            currentYear = i;

            if (theChange > amountOfChange)
            {
                amountOfChange = theChange;
                changeInYears = i;
            }
        }

        return changeInYears;
    }

    private int LeastIncrease(List<int> PopulationList)                                 //Imports the population list to Least.
    {
        int firstItem = PopulationList.First();
        int lastItem = PopulationList.Last();

        int amountOfChange = (lastItem - firstItem);
        int changeInYears = 0;
        int i;
        int theChange = 0;
        int CurrentYear = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < PopulationList.Count(); i++)
        {
            theChange = PopulationList[i] - PopulationList[i - 1];
            CurrentYear = i;

            if (theChange < amountOfChange)
            {
                amountOfChange = theChange;
                changeInYears = i;
            }
        }

        return changeInYears;
    }
```

Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please comment on answers that don't quite answer your question, and Mark as Answer the one that best fits. Often times your comments on answers will lead to ways to improve the question you are asking as well.

Answer (score 1):

The code iterates through a list, thats what the loop is for.

amountOfChange stores the maximum change up to the current position of the list.

changeInYears stores the position in the list where the changed occurred. If i is the year, the change ocurred between i-1 to i.

Since there is no change in the first year(i=0), you start comparing since the second year(i=1) with the previous year (Thats why the list starts at position 1).

theChange and currentYear, are temporal values for storing the current change, which is then compared to the current maximum(changeInYears) and updated if the change is greater than current maximum (so is the position, changeInYears). This is calculated as the difference between current value and the previous value in the List.

The second method, does exactly the same, but stores the minimum.

Hope It Helps

Comment: thank you for the help it. i now understand exactly what it was doing.

Answer (score 0):

The code goes through the items in the list, starting from the second, and subtracts that value from the previous item's value.  That's the "difference" between items.  Item then takes the min/max of that value by keeping track of the highest/lowest value computed so far and comparing it to the latest computed difference.  If it determines that the last computed difference is higher/lower than the optimal value it stores both the value of that difference and the index at which it took place.